# Warp perspective 4 point like OpenCV in GPUImage

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, gpuimage, perspective

I am quite familiar with OpenCV but i'm pretty new now with GPUImage. I want to implement warp- perspective 4 point like OpenCV in GPUImage.

You should look [description, images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIbC9.png). In OpenCV I have implemented [warpPerspective](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/perspective-transform.html) for crop and transform it from the quad (the bounds of orange) to the rectangle (renderview black bound).

First, i pass orange p1, p2, p3, p4 and black p'1, p'2, p'3, p'4 to OpenCV: getPerspectiveTransform for calculating MAP_MATRIX.

After that, pass MAP_MATRIX to OpenCV: warpPerspective (srcMat,dstMat, MAP_MATRIX). And the results are on the right side.
In OpenCV, i use code block below.

```
  // The 4 points that select quadilateral on the input , from top-left in clockwise order
// These four pts are the sides of the rect box used as input 
inputQuad[0] = Point2f( -30,-60 );//p1
inputQuad[1] = Point2f( input.cols+50,-50);//p2
inputQuad[2] = Point2f( input.cols+100,input.rows+50);//p3
inputQuad[3] = Point2f( -50,input.rows+50  );//p4  
// The 4 points where the mapping is to be done , from top-left in clockwise order
outputQuad[0] = Point2f( 0,0 );//p'1
outputQuad[1] = Point2f( input.cols-1,0);//p'2
outputQuad[2] = Point2f( input.cols-1,input.rows-1);//p'3
outputQuad[3] = Point2f( 0,input.rows-1  );//p'4

// Get the Perspective Transform Matrix i.e. MAP_MATRIX
lambda = getPerspectiveTransform( inputQuad, outputQuad );
// Apply the Perspective Transform just found to the src image
warpPerspective(input,output,lambda,output.size() );
```

Please give me some guidelines to start and achieve it.
Thanks so much!

Comment: I would suggest breaking your question into paragraphs, it is very difficult to read. I cannot help you with the actual question, though.

Comment: @EvanCarslake thank you, i have edited it.